# Nativescript Vue RadListView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished is not a function

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm using Nativescript + Vue.js + nativescript-ui-listview. I have an error RadListView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished is not a function (tried both Android / iOS). Wrapped `notifyLoadOnDemandFinished()` in a `setTimeout` as it advised in this [issue](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/511) but it didn't help. Other 'notify' methods for example `notifySwipeToExecuteFinished` works fine.
Here is a link to my [code](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=BgquKt&v=6) (nativescript playground).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using references in Vue, you must use the `.nativeView` property to gain access to the actual component. So it should be,

```
this.$refs.listView.nativeView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished();
```